# Ambiguous step definitions in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I have two steps like:

```
When the user launches site with the base configuration with url parameter set to http://www.youtube.com
When the user launches site with the base configuration
```

These two steps are in two different scenarios.
While running automation I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: cucumber.runtime.AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException.

  When the user launches site with the base configuration with url parameter set to http://www.youtube.com(android-config.feature:37) matches more than one step definition:
  the user launches site with the base configuration in ConfigGlue.launches the base configuration()
  the user launches site with the base configuration with url parameter set to(.*) in ConfigGlue.the user launches the cnfiguration(String)
```

How can I use the same step definition for these two steps.

Comment: Would you please provide your step definitions? Exactly do you define them?

Comment: Well, it's obvious, you have that particular step implemented more than once, or you are using some regular expression for the 2 steps stated that could both fall in the same one... sharing your step definition code would be helpful to understand what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your step definition should look like:

```
When(/^the user launches site with the base configuration( with url parameter set to (.*))?$/) do |custom, url|
  if custom
    p "Using custom url: #{url}"
  end
end
```

**Note:** That's Ruby. I guess for Java regular expression will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your step definitions regex are distinct for the two when conditions in the feature file(s), there should not be any cucumber ambiguous error. You can try below step definitions keeping the entire feature file lines as is. I use this like below in Ruby, should be similar in Java.

```
When("the user launches site with the base configuration with url parameter set to http://www.youtube.com") do
   # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When("the user launches site with the base configuration") do
   # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

Or like below:

```
When(/^the user launches site with the base configuration with url parameter set to http://www.youtube.com$/) do
   # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^the user launches site with the base configuration$/) do
   # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```